# How to dynamically add a field to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my form I would like to dynamically add a field when the checkbox is checked.

The `.select-qty` has css `dislpay: none`

```
<%= form_with model: @item,  html: { class: "update-form", method: :patch, remote: true }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, value: item.id %>
  <td class="mulitple-item">
    <%= f.check_box :selected, { checked: true, value: item.selected, class: 'form-control', onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %>
 </td>
 <td class="select-qty>
  <%= f.select :quantity, options_for_select((0..item.quantity), selected: 2), {}, { value: item.quantity, class: 'form-control', onchange: 'this.form.submit();' } %>
 </td>
<% end %>
```

I have this `update.js.erb`which is supposed to make the field appeared...

```
$('.multiple-item').bind('.update-form').bind('.submit-btn').bind('ajax:success', function(){
 $(".select-qty").css("display", "block")
});
```

in my routes i have this:

```
patch "items", to: "items#update",  defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

and my controller `#update`

```
def update
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
     @item.update_attributes(item_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
    end
 end
```

When I check the checkbox it renders the raw code of the `update.js.erb` in the browser...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`method` and `remote` shouldn't be inside `html: {}` hash, since those are not actually html attributes, but options of the `form_with` helper method.

In fact, an html form has the `method` attribute, however this option is usually passed to `form_with` method outside of `html` hash, as Rails not only includes it in the generated html form as an attribute, but also does something else.

This is the right way:

```
<%= form_with model: @item,  method: :patch, remote: true, html: {class: "update-form"}  do |f| %>
```

Comment: thanks for helping, I removed `method` and `remote` from the `html: {}` and put it the same as you've shown, but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally removed the `defaults {format: :js}`in my routes

```
patch "items", to: "items#update"
```

and I added the html format in my update method....

```
def update
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
     @item.update_attributes(item_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
     format.html {redirect_to my_path}
    end
 end
```